# Pgadmin4 Error: Application server could not be contacted

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have installed a `pgadmin 4` on my mac os High Sierra and I'm getting an error that says `the application server could not be contacted`.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt5 runtime is causing many issues on MacOS High sierra, If you need a 
 workaround then you could try out latest development version, https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/runtime-revamp/

For more information on this dev build you can refer: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxozDyrZHDGPmP%2Bx8h11yn2mZmtv42x_dBOu3mBcrMf6NBA%40mail.gmail.com